# issue with virtual keyboard scrolling in BB LWUIT

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-vkb

I have done a j2me application when I port it to Blackberry using LWUIT framework I have a problem in virtual keyboard as it does not automatically scrolls because of which the user is unable to view what he is typing in the text field .

Can help me solve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: I think that VK has already its own textfield where the user can see what is typying.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem in many platforms that feature a VKB. Currently LWUIT doesn't make solving that problem seamless which it should (feel free to file an issue on that, this should be resolved for Android/RIM, in J2ME the input is within the VKB itself).

To resolve it for now you can either change your UI to place the text field in a location that is more easily reachable to the VKB. Alternatively you can try to scroll it up when detecting touch (before invoking super), this obviously requires quite a bit of coding and isn't trivial.

Comment: Well I see the problem being fixed in dialogs whr the dialog automatically scrolls up when the virtualkeyboard is ON can you tell me hw is it possible for dialog.

Comment: The BB resizes the screen when the VKB is shown which effectively shrinks the dialog. With Forms the behavior is more complex since their scrolling might work differently in such cases. You can scroll to the field although its not exactly intuitive.